# oci_connect() can't connect - command Line with codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, command-line-interface, oracle-call-interface

Although calling the same script through browser work fine, trying to trigger the same script via CLI didn't work!
The way I have to call the script I use [CodeIgniter structure](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html) :

```
php index.php controller/function/parameter
```

I have also change in config file of my project:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'
```

But the problem that oci can't work within cli although it works by calling it using the browser.

THis error appear:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\MYPROJECT\syst
em\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php on line 238**

> Severity:    Error Message:     Call to undefined function
>   oci_connect() Filename:
>   C:\wamp64\www\MYPROJECT\system\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php
>   Line Number: 238

I have enabled the oci extension at php.ini

> extension=php_oci8_12c.dll

which is existed in the following directory:

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes I restarted Apache

Comment: Can you check with `php -m` on cli to see if oci8 module is enabled

Comment: there is no oci8!

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: @Hana90 Can you find what is the location of the phi.ini used by cli by running this command `php --ini`. Once you find it, check if this `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` is enabled. If you have to enable it, then restart the server.

Comment: Make sure the console you are using has the Oracle client libraries in PATH.